# Facebook login in react-native WebView

Tags: webview, react-native, facebook-login

I am developing a simple web browser (WebView) using `react-native`.

Everything works well except logging into Facebook.

The website has a Facebook login and when I tap it, it takes me to the in-app mobile Facebook login page. Entering the correct user/pass redirects me to `/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=https://staticxx.facebook.com/connect.......` and I get stuck there.

Without using `react-native-fbsdk` how do I solve this?

Using the same site on desktop and mobile safari works well. (Although it opens a new tab).

Trying https://meetup.com fails as well but https://vimeo.com works well.

Is there anything I should be aware of or is it a problem with the websites?